# Missing source code in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

As you can see, `View` class is present.

[image]

However, `ViewRootImpl` is not there. But I can still navigate to that class? How to fix this?

Comment: you want to see the source code of ViewRootImpl right?

Comment: Yeah, dont know why its not showing

Comment: try open your SDK, then install Source for Android SDK. then restart Android Studio and check ViewRootImpl class again

Comment: No it doesn't work...can you see that class?

Comment: Have you tried ctrl + shift + R ?

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal that's not relevant to open class source code

Comment: @WenChao Sir I was just trying to help. Actually, I am not an android developer as you are. I am a student of computer science and exploring my world in android for past 1 year. Sorry for taking your time Sir !

Comment: @WenChao Sir you can have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106285/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-for-classes-in-the-android-sdk  It shows there might be a problem with the Compiled SDK version